# Sampling by group without repetition using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'll use a hypothetical scenario to illustrate the question. Here's a table with musicians and the instrument they play and a table with the composition for a band:

```
musicians <- data.table(
  instrument = rep(c('bass','drums','guitar'), each = 4),
  musician = c('Chas','John','Paul','Stuart','Andy','Paul','Peter','Ringo','George','John','Paul','Ringo')
)

band.comp <- data.table(
  instrument = c('bass','drums','guitar'),
  n = c(2,1,2)
)
```

To avoid arguments about who is best with which instrument, the band will be assembled by sortition. Here's how I'm doing:

```
musicians[band.comp, on = 'instrument'][, sample(musician, n), by = instrument]

   instrument     V1
1:       bass   Paul
2:       bass   Chas
3:      drums   Andy
4:     guitar   Paul
5:     guitar George
```

The problem is: since there are musicians who play more than one instrument, it can happen that one person is drawn more than once.

One can build a for loop that, for each subsequent subset of instruments, draws musicians and then eliminates those from the rest of the table. But I would like suggestions on how to do this using data.table. Mainly because the kind of problem I need to solve in real life with this logic involves data bases with hundreds of thousands of rows. And also because I'm trying to better understand the data.table syntax.

As a reference, I tried some [tips from Andrew Brooks blog](https://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#calculate-a-function-over-a-group-using-by-excluding-each-entity-in-a-second-category), but couldn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across a relevant post: [Randomly draw rows from dataframe based on unique values and column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473974/randomly-draw-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-unique-values-and-column-values/46477442#46477442) and eddi's answer is perfect for this OP:

```
#keep number of musicians per instrument in 1 data.table
musicians[band.comp, n:=n, on=.(instrument)]

#for storing the musician that has been sampled so far
m <- c()

musicians[, {
    #exclude sampled musician before sampling
    res <- .SD[!musician %chin% m][sample(.N, n[1L])]
    m <- c(m, res$musician)
    res
}, by=.(instrument)]
```

sample output:

```
   instrument musician n
1:       bass   Stuart 2
2:       bass     Chas 2
3:      drums     Paul 1
4:     guitar     John 2
5:     guitar    Ringo 2
```

---

Or more succinctly with error handling as well:

```
m <- c()
musicians[
    band.comp, 
    on=.(instrument), 
    j={
        s <- setdiff(musician, m)
        if (length(s) < n) stop(paste("Not enough musicians playing", .BY))
        res <- sample(s, n)    
        m <- c(m, res)
        res
    }, 
    by=.EACHI]
```

Comment: Honestly, eddi deserves the credit. Please upvote his answer on the other OP instead of this

Answer (score 5):

This can be a solution, first you select an instrument by musician and then you select the musicians of your sample. But it may be that when selecting an instrument per musician your sample size is larger than the population then you will get an error (but in your real data this may not be a problem).

```
musicians[, .(instrument = sample(instrument, 1)), by = musician][band.comp, on = 'instrument'][, sample(musician, n), by = instrument]
```

Comment: Perplexed by the downvote. This appears to be a good solution.

Comment: That's clever, it hadn't occurred to me to follow this line. With big data sets the sample size should not be a problem, indeed, unless there's a lot of categories and a lot of repetitions. For example, when Netflix keeps suggesting the same movie in different categories.

Comment: i am sorry. was too fast with downvoting at that time cos it does not work some time. in retrospect, it was a good soln. have been wanting to reverse but its locked in without editing. has edited with spaces and reversed the downvote n upvote instead. my sincere apologies

Answer (score 3):

You could expand the band comp into `sum(band.comp$n)` distinct positions and keep sampling until you find a feasible composition:

```
roles = musicians[, 
  CJ(posn = 1:band.comp[.BY, on=.(instrument), x.n], musician = musician)
, by=instrument]

set.seed(1)
while (TRUE){
  roles[sample(1:.N), keep := !duplicated(.SD, by="musician") & !duplicated(.SD, by=c("instrument", "posn"))][]
  if (sum(roles$keep) == sum(band.comp$n)) break
}

setorder(roles[keep == TRUE, !"keep"])[]

   instrument posn musician
1:       bass    1   Stuart
2:       bass    2     John
3:      drums    1     Andy
4:     guitar    1   George
5:     guitar    2     Paul
```

There's probably something you could do with linear programming or a bipartite graph to answer the question of whether a feasible comp exists, but it's unclear what "sampling" even means in terms of the distribution over feasible comps.

Comment: This is very good. It avoids the concern of bias in approaches that eliminates individuals from the whole data set and is much faster than a loop with subset. But the idea is to completely avoid loops and use just data.table syntax because I'm dealing with huge sets being fetched from SQL data bases.

Comment: @Carlos As long as `roles` (a table in R, since data.table does not support queries vs DB connections) can fit in memory, I guess that is not a problem. Inside the loop, it's just temporarily jumbling the table's rows (in R), not creating it anew. With big enough values in `band.comp$n`, this approach might fail when building `roles`, though.

Comment: @Frank You're right, I was following the wrong line of reasoning. I wanted to avoid multiplying the data, so I was thinking in some solution involving excluding lines. The `roles` table may indeed be too large for memory in some cases, but I just need to read the id and category columns, draw, and then use the resulting id vector to get the complete data. Thanks for the insights.